# What is the React way of adding a child element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below code:

```
<TreeView
    aria-label="controlled"
    defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
    defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronLeftIcon />}
    expanded={expanded}
    selected={selected}
    onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
    onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
    multiSelect
>
  {
    rows.data.map((item: IPTreeModel)=> {
      return (
          <TreeItem nodeId={item.id} label={item.subnet} onClick={item.has_child ? (e: MouseEvent)=> loadChildren(e, item.subnet) : ()=> ''}>
              {/*here*/}
          </TreeItem>
      )
    })
  }
</TreeView>
```

And below is my function:

```
  const loadChildren = (e: MouseEvent, id: number | string) => {
      // fetch new data based on the ID parameter, and append the output as a TreeItem element.                   
  }
```

Now I need to append a new `<TreeItem>` element  to the last `<TreeItem>` in case user clicks on `loadChildren` function.

How is the react way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving the issue like below:

```
const loadChildren = (e: any, id: number | string) => {
      setLoadingChildren(true)
      getIpState(id).then(res=> {
          setRows({
              ...rows,
              data: rows.data.map((item: any) => item.id == id ? {...item, child: res.data} : item)
          })
          setLoadingChildren(false)
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          setLoadingChildren(false)
      })
  }


const traverse = (o: any) => {
  if (!loadingChildren){
      return o.map((item: any, key: number) => {
      let extra = item.hasOwnProperty('extra') ? item.extra : item
              return (
                  <TreeItem key={key} nodeId={extra.id} icon={item.has_child ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : ''} label={item.subnet} onClick={extra.has_child ? (e)=> loadChildren(e, extra.id) : ()=> ''}>
                      {item.child ?  traverse(item.child) : ''}
                  </TreeItem>
              )
          }
      )
  }
}
```

And display the output like:

```
<TreeView
    aria-label="controlled"
    defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
    defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronLeftIcon />}
    expanded={expanded}
    selected={selected}
    onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
    onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
    multiSelect
>
    {traverse(rows.data)}
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field to your `rows.data` object and make sure to store it as a state.
do this by cloning your previous array, doing a pushback and then setting a new state with your new modified array.
This will trigger the redraw of the `TreeView` component.

Edit 1:

Here's a quick example of how you could do this.
Have an onClick call the addData function to add data to your structure.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const addData = () => {
    const tmp = data.slice();
    tmp.push([new data]);
    setData(tmp);
  }
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TreeView>
        {data.map((item) => {
          <TreeItem data={item} ></TreeItem>
        })}
      </TreeView>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: MFischer consider adding some code demonstrating your solution

Comment: MFischer, thank you so much for your time, I appreciate it a lot, but I think I should go for the recursive way of outputting TreeItem elements, since every children may have another children I can not do it in a linear way using set of array elements.